# How to view the content of DbgPrint?

Tags: windows-7, driver, wdk

I am new to driver programming.I have created one simple driver in windows 7 .I try to install  in my kernel using osrloader? Whether osrloader works in windows 7 32 bit ?I use DbgPrint in my coding if i want to see the printing details means How can i see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. connect WinDbg (you must have 2 separated computers or use VM instead)
2. Use DbgView http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx, you can use this tool on the same computer there you load driver.